# How can i delete role permissinos with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I accidentally did this [image] in every channel with my bot. How can i remove them using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextChannel.set_permissions` to modify the permissions for a certain channel, in your case just iterate over the channels that you need.

To be able to delete the permissions you will need to set the `overwrite` parameter to `None`:

```py
@client.command()
async def delete_perms(ctx):
    channel_list = [ ]  # Here goes the list of channel IDs to modify
    member_list = [ ] # Here goes the list of member IDs that you want to remove permissions
    for channel in channel_list:
        channel_i = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel)
        for member in member_list:
            member_i = ctx.guild.get_member(member)
            await channel_i.set_permissions(member_i, overwrite=None)
```

References:

- [TextChannel.set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)

Comment: TypeError: object TextChannel can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: My bad, try not awaiting the `get_channel` and `get_member` functions.